# Trigger successive airflow wokflow using TriggerDag operator based on the inputs from file

Tags: python, airflow

I need to trigger the workflow to generate multiple workflow for the same dag with different inputs from file.Unfortunately it get trigger for only input 302406 .Not for other two inputs mentioned ie 302405 &302404.Below is code

Conditional Trigger

```
def conditionally_trigger(context, dag_run_obj):
    testsite_array = []
    with open('/etc/dev/airflow/dags/input.txt') as my_file:
        for line in my_file:
            testsite_array.append(int(line))
    for i in testsite_array:
        dag_run_obj.payload = {
                'message': i
            }
        pp.pprint(dag_run_obj.payload)
    return dag_run_obj

with DAG(dag_id="triggerdagop_controller_dag", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="@once") as dag:
    trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id="trigger_dag",
        trigger_dag_id="bdf_load_report",
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=conditionally_trigger,
    )
```

Content of input file

302405
302404
302406

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger dynamically based on the input from file as mentioned below:

```
def conditionally_trigger(context, dag_run_obj):
if context['params']:
    dag_run_obj.payload = {
            'message': context['params']['message']
        }
    pp.pprint(dag_run_obj.payload)
    return dag_run_obj


with open('/etc/dev/airflow/dags/input.txt') as my_file:
 for line in my_file:
    trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id="triggerdagop_controller_dag_{}".format(int(line)),
        trigger_dag_id="bdf_load_report",
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=conditionally_trigger,
        params={'message': line},
        timeout=600,
        mode="reschedule",
        dag=dag
        )
    trigger
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses a `python_callable` like a `PythonOperator` but `TriggerDagRunOperator` [only really accepts](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py) a `dag_id` and `execution_date`.

This suggests you're doing  something outside of Airflow functionality and need to do some extra work or research to get what you want.

---

Ultimately your function amends the `payload` each time it iterates through your list. But each time it amends inside that loop, it overwrites the attribute. You end up returning only one object. Which corresponds to the last value in the iteration.

This is likely your issue. You might instead want to have your for  loop logic tied to something else, or around the creation  of the Tasks themselves.

Comment: Thanks mike for the response .I have used the TriggerDagRunOperator  which passes the argument  to subDag using python callable.It does not give any error so you can use python callable in TriggerDagRunOperator  . Coming to next point  Yes I am able to return the argument at end of  execution of  the loop. Can you suggest other alternative to pass argument multiple times to TriggerDagOperator ?

Comment: Hi Abhishek, that is a a bit of a design flaw in Airflow Operators. They will nearly all accept all arguments you pass them, and will do so quietly. They will take them and throw them away, and provide a warning only.

Accordingly, while you do and can pass the python_callable, it won't do anything with it. Please check the source code linked in my answer to see that python_callable is not used.